# Heroku logging body of response

Tags: php, cakephp, heroku

I have a php server running on a Heroku instance and would like to log the server responses including the body. Now maybe this is a bad idea as this could cause the logs to get very large very quickly. The problem I'm having is an API call returns a 200 response but an invalid body. I am unable to reliably reproduce and would like to capture the response to be able to inspect the JSON to determine what is causing the intermittent failures. I've used the `heroku logs` command but this does not provide enough info to debug the issue. Is there an add on Heroku offers for full body logging?

Comment: Use something like Postman to perform the request manually and inspect the output, or invoke the script with another script and check the output you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku logs do NOT log the body by default. If you want to log the body, the solution is simple:

Modify your PHP program running on Heroku to print the body of the request when it is received to the console. Anything you PRINT in your application code will show up in the Heroku logs.

Comment: i tried using print and echo, but nothing showed in the logs